# How to punish scamer

Tags: scam

I really hope, this is the right place to ask that sort of question.
If the topic is against rules place just lock/remove it. I hope I won't get banned :D. Anyway I feel I should ask this here.

On this site: http://wpolityce.pl from time to time appears scam add (why it is scam, I will show and explain in the bottom part of this question).

It is on polish website and the add is also in polish.
It is the one in bottom right corner:
[image]

The link full link of this add is: http://nextclick.pl/widget/redirect.php?id=1496238132041780&key=64F2-9389-907A-45C3-1c1weX&domain=wpolityce.pl&loc=2739623358945765913164529494315307059905185555962876832349368052:|SGFtYnVyZw==&pid=40276951&pv=bfd48b5a-51f5-11e7-8c51-000000000000

After redirection, the site url looks like this: http://dziennik-edukacyjny.pl/artykuly/nowa-metoda-przyswajania-jezykow-as/?utm_campaign=nxt-1&utm_content=300x180_neblondie_103_232&utm_medium=banner&utm_source=nba

I wanted to report this add in polish office, and maybe I will do so, but first I want to mess with them for a while.

For now I just run this command in PowerShell:

```
while(1) { curl -v -UseBasicParsing "http://nextclick.pl/widget/redirect.php?id=1496238132041780&key=64F2-9389-907A-45C3-1c1weX&domain=wpolityce.pl&loc=2739623358945765913164529494315307059905185555962876832349368052:|SGFtYnVyZw==&pid=40276951&pv=bfd48b5a-51f5-11e7-8c51-000000000000"; }
```

So I have this responses in infinite loop:
[image]

So basically I want to make fake clicks on the add banner, and here is my question: What is the best way to punish that scammers? Will my load of requests be treated as one cause of same IP client?

Why it is scam?
They try to sell you some stuff that let you learn any language in 2 weeks.
Well everything is fake there, except payment channel.
Fake facebook comments with stolen facebook account avatars etc.
Not to mention the the product itself is complete scam - no information there is true, not to mention that there is actually no info how that should work.
Also this domain: http://dziennik-edukacyjny.pl means in English "educational newspaper" and in root is out of any page.

Comment: I understand your desire to punish them, but I think the question is not a great fit for a Q&A site because it's mostly about opinions, grey-area methods and not so much about getting definitive answers.

Comment: @Arminius true, but this is the only place I know I could ask. Still I completely agree with you. Anyway I will leave this question as it is now, cause sometimes I see broad, opinion based questions that had really good and precise answers that I was looking for. Maybe sometimes it is good to bend the rules.